# C# code to delete a file from FTP through Proxy

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ftp

How do I get around this error

```
**The Requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP Proxy**
```

occur on the following code

```
ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile.
```

It is urgent. Can anyone give suggestions for this problem

Comment: are you using internet with proxy server???like ISA?

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy might be blocking FTP delete keywords when filtering requests.
Can you check if you are able to do this activity when not in the proxy (try from a different network where you connect directly).
if yes, i dont think it is straighforward for you to do this activity from behind proxy.

Another solution is to try open source ftps libraries http://ftps.codeplex.com/
or 
1. Create a WCF service on the FTP server which allows you to do all that you want.
2. From client side make call to the WCF service passing the command.